# Multer in Nodejs using Express Router req.file undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, express-router

I am trying to implement File Upload functionality using multer and Express Router. I defined an endpoint `/batch_upload` using **router.use** like below

api.js

```js
router.use(
  "/batch_upload",
  upload.single("emp_csv_data"),
  userController.processBatchUserInformation
);
```

in **userController.js**

```js
exports.processBatchUserInformation = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);

  if (req.method == "POST") {
    try {
      console.log("Upload route reached - POST");
      console.log(req.file);
      console.log(req.file.path);
      return res.send(req.file);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error Occurred");
      return res.send(err);
    }

  }
};
```

In the **FileUploader.js**, I defined the upload variable and multer options like below

```js
var multer = require("multer");

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    return cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now());
  }
});


exports.upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

Finally, in the app.js I used the route using
`app.use('/user',user_routes)`

But when I send a file to `http://localhost:5000/user/batch_upload`, I get an undefined response for `req.file`

[image]

Irony is that I have the exact implementation in a sample test project and everything seems fine. I don't understand what am I missing. If you see something that seems off, please help me fix it.

Comment: To help put things into context, could you maybe paste in the code that puts together the request for this endpoint?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by code for the 'request'. The endpoint is created by router.use, multer options are mentioned, and also the controller method. The request object will be a simple form-data with a file.

Comment: Ok. How do you actually send a request to http://localhost:5000/user/batch_upload? Is this done by submitting a plain html form? Or is it handled programmatically with a javascript library? Can you paste this information in your post please, maybe it will help.

Comment: I am using Postman. I will update the post with a screenshot. Please take a look at it.

Comment: what do you have in the log? Is the folder `uploads` exist and you have permission to write in this folder?

Comment: Yes, the folder exists. and I am not sure how I would check folder permissions. I am currently running the server locally.

Answer (score 0):

So, the reason behind the file not being uploaded was that I did not add **Content-type:multipart/form-data** in the headers. Thank you guys for trying to help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Strange. "Website forms often send data to APIs as multipart/form-data. You can replicate this in Postman using the form-data Body tab." Which is what you originally did, right? Good to hear you managed to sort this out anyway. https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#sending-body-data